# О различиях запятой перед тире и двоеточием

Tags: пунктуация

Встретилась вот такая конструкция:

«Выпрыгивающий из тостера хлеб, являющийся причиной инфаркта у котов: уголовно правовая характеристика»

И вот, что удивляет. Обычно, когда речь идёт о причастных (и других) оборотах на стыке с длинным тире, аргументируют, что оборот во что бы то ни стало должен быть закрыт запятой и даже тире этого не отменяет. Но ведь мы же не ставим запятую перед двоеточием, чтобы обязательно закрыть оборот? Двоеточие вполне может «съесть» запятую. А почему тире не может? Почему обязательно закрывать обороты «как», «что» и другие?

Неужели есть разница между:

«Выпрыгивающий из тостера хлеб, являющийся причиной инфаркта у котов, — это неприятность».

И

«Выпрыгивающий из тостера хлеб, являющийся причиной инфаркта у котов — это неприятность»?

На мой взгляд, конструкция с запятой перед тире смотрится громоздко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не думаю, что этим вопросом всерьез кто-то озадачивался их авторитетных специалистов по правописанию... Но вообще-то объяснение есть.

> Неужели есть разница между:

Зрительная разница есть. В первом случае сразу видно, что тире находится **после** причастного оборота, а во втором можно предположить, что **внутри**. И во всех подобных случая запятая сохраняется, что вполне логично по тем же соображениям.

В этом и отличия от стечения запятой и двоеточия. Двоеточие всегда ставится в тех случаях, кода структура предложения не допускает подобной двусмысленности, следующая за двоеточием часть синтаксически всегда подчинена предшествующей. Это касается всех трех (или четырех согласно Правилам-56) случаях нормативного использования двоеточия.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/157-dvoe
(§ 159 и § 160 - это в общем-то один случай)

Особняком, правда, стоит двоеточие, оформляющее прямую речь, там двоеточие, кавычки, запятая и тире по сути дела ставятся по единому мотиву, но это не принципиально, проблем с восприятием не возникает.

Это всё в общем-то объяснение внутренней логики, повторюсь, не думаю, что именно так рассуждали творцы пунктуации.

Comment: А как тогда быть с такими ситуациями: "Имена, которые он произносил машинально еще утром — имена тех, кто, быть может, будет обладать ею, опять стали приходить ему на память в то время, как глаза его следили за мухой, которая подлетала к его пальцу, точно хотела коснуться его, затем улетала и снова возвращалась, но не дотрагивалась до него"? Здесь запятая отсутствует по ошибке редактора? Ведь "которые" нужно тоже обособлять. Так получается?

Comment: Вот и не знаю наверняка, ошибка ли. Скорее как раз нет, тут логично считать, что придаточное тут цельное: *которые он произносил машинально еще утром — имена тех, кто, быть может, будет обладать ею*. Потому что именно этот кусок, целиком можно изъять из текста, не нарушая грамматики оставшейся части, а вот с половинкой (до тире) так не получится. И тогда получается, мотивов для запятой перед тире просто нет. Если бы текст не был переводным, я бы сказал это с большей уверенностью. А так остается положиться только на понимание переводчика.